# Error with input shapes for TimeseriesGenerator in a LSTM stacked RNN

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I am trying to create a model forecasting future stock data using 13 data features.  I am using a TimeseriesGenerator but when I try to fit my model I am getting an error saying:

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have shape (529, 13) but got array with shape (5, 13)

my dataset has 529 rows that I want to use to train to predict the next 5 days.  Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Part 1 - Data Preprocessing

# Importing the Libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator


# Importing the Training Set
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
training_set_indicators = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:14].values


# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
training_set_indicators_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set_indicators)
final_dataset = training_set_indicators_scaled


# Part 2 - Building the RNN

# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout


n_features = final_dataset.shape[1]
n_lag = 5

generator = TimeseriesGenerator(final_dataset, final_dataset, length = n_lag, batch_size = 8)

# Initializing the RNN
regressor = Sequential()


# Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout Regularization
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 250, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (final_dataset.shape[0], final_dataset.shape[1])))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))


# Adding the second LSTM layer and some Dropout Regularization
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 250))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))


# Adding the Output Layer
regressor.add(Dense(units = 13))


# Compiling the RNN
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')


# Fitting the RNN to the Training Set
regressor.fit_generator(generator, epochs = 100, verbose = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `length` parameter in `TimeseriesGenerator` refers to the number of timesteps to extract from the sequence. Therefore, in your example with `length=n_lag`, as `n_lag=5`, your generator is generating subsequences of length 5.

The error is being thrown because you have set

```
input_shape = (final_dataset.shape[0], final_dataset.shape[1])
```

and `final_dataset.shape[0]=529` so your model expects input sequences of length 529.

As for

> predict the next 5 days

you need to decide whether you want to predict 5 days after a selection of subsequences in your current sequence, or whether you wish to predict 5 days after the full sequence (which would require 5 more labelled time points to train against). In both cases you should consider feeding the output of your RNN back in as the input.

Comment: Thanks Jacob!  I got it to work doing what you suggested by adjusting the input shape.  But just confused on what you mean by "In both cases you should consider feeding the output of your RNN back in as the input." do you mean in terms of backpropogating how would the output be redirected to be the input?

Comment: For instance, if you train your model to predict step N+1, given step N, then to predict 5 steps into the future you will need to input step N+1 and repeat the process.